# jquery while loop with counter not starting

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I was trying to create a while loop in JQuery

```
$(document).ready(function () {
//startgame();
var game = {
    started: false,
    jumper: 0, //player jump active or not
    seconds: 0
}

$('body').keyup(function (space) {
    if (space.keyCode == 32) { //32 = spatie

        if (game.started != true) { //set game to started
            game.started = true;
            console.log("game started? " + game.started);
        };

        if (game.jumper == 0) { //start jump
            game.jumper = 1; //jump is in action
            $("#player").animate({ //animate to air
                top: "-=75"
            }, 250, function () {
                $(this).animate({ //return to ground
                    top: "+=75"
                }, 500, function () {
                    game.jumper = 0;
                });
            });
        }
    }
}); //end space

//not even running this code
while (game.started == "true") {
    var squaretimer = Math.random(1000, 3000);
    console.log(squaretimer);
    $("#border").append("<div class='driehoek'></div>");
}
});
```

No error's in console.
So the idea is eventually the code spawns (random in 1/3 secs a new div)
But the whole while loop isn's running. Did I do something wrong?

Comment: The while loop is entered and exited immediately after the DOM is loaded.

Comment: Probabaly because you're comparing a `boolean` with a `string`?

Comment: `game.started` only gets set to true when you press space, so when it hits the while loop, you haven't pressed space and so it's false - exits while immediately.

Comment: @freedomn-m it's wrong either way.

Comment: loop will not run because condition will be false on DOM ready

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to something like this.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
//startgame();
var game = {
    started: false,
    jumper: 0, //player jump active or not
    seconds: 0
}

$('body').keyup(function (space) {
    if (space.keyCode == 32) { //32 = spatie

        if (game.started != true) { //set game to started
            game.started = true;
            console.log("game started? " + game.started);
        };

        if (game.jumper == 0) { //start jump
            game.jumper = 1; //jump is in action
            $("#player").animate({ //animate to air
                top: "-=75"
            }, 250, function () {
                $(this).animate({ //return to ground
                    top: "+=75"
                }, 500, function () {
                    game.jumper = 0;
                });
            });
        }
    }
}); //end space

//not even running this code
while (game.started) {
    var squaretimer = Math.random(1000, 3000);
    console.log(squaretimer);
    $("#border").append("<div class='driehoek'></div>");
}
});
```

Comment: still not running

Comment: Means "game.started" is always comes in false...debug your code. because while loop condtion is currect... try to add game.started= true and check while loop working...

Answer (score 1):

You are comparing a boolean with a string, you should do something like this :

```
while(game.started){
....
}
```

**UPDATE:**
Additionnaly, the loop is called right away, before you start the game by pressing start. You need to execute it right after. You could :

Put the loop in a function :

```
function startLoop() {
  while (game.started) {
      var squaretimer = Math.random(1000, 3000);
      console.log(squaretimer);
      $("#border").append("<div class='driehoek'></div>");
  }
}
```

Then call it when you start the game :

```
$('body').keyup(function (space) {
    if (space.keyCode == 32) { //32 = spatie

        if (game.started != true) { //set game to started
            game.started = true;
            console.log("game started? " + game.started);
            startLoop();
        };

        if (game.jumper == 0) { //start jump
            game.jumper = 1; //jump is in action
            $("#player").animate({ //animate to air
                top: "-=75"
            }, 250, function () {
                $(this).animate({ //return to ground
                    top: "+=75"
                }, 500, function () {
                    game.jumper = 0;
                });
            });
        }
    }
}); //end space
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(body).keyup(function(space) {
    //your code
    someFunction(game.started);
});

function someFunction(a) {
    this.a = a;
    while (this.a) {
        // your code again
    }
}
// The purpose of calling function is that it binds in keyup event
```

Comment: Please do not post bare code, also provide an explanation for what the code is doing.

Answer (score 0):

```
while (game.started == "true")
```

It should be

```
while (game.started == true)
```